# Inject Open generic interface in DI container in c#

Tags: c#

```
public interface A<T> { T GetValue(); }

public class B<T> : A<T> { private readonly string _key;

public B(string key)
{
    _key = key;
}

public T GetValue()
{
    return default(T);
}

}
```

how to register above class in DI container in c# . services.Addscoped(typeof(A<>),typeof(B<>)) won't work because of constructor parameter in class B

it is giving class not constructed due to parameter

Comment: You can't. You could register a factory, though. Either way: You _must_ provide the argument. Or find a way to _inject_ the argument itself, too.

Comment: If on .Net 8, you may also be interested in [Keyed Services](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/net-8-dependency-injection-changes-keyed-services)

Comment: Why exactly do you need? Seems to be [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you please explain actual use-case?